# Getting None when trying to use pysftp to get file

Tags: python, sftp, pysftp

I need to get files from server and next write them to database.
I use:

```
with pysftp.Connection(host, username=username, password=password, cnopts=cnopts) as sftp:
    sftp.chdir('path')
    all_files = [file_name for file_name in sftp.listdir() if 'access' in file_name]
    today_log = all_files[0]
    all_files = all_files[1:]
    df = df.append(sftp.get(str(today_log)))
```

But it returns `None`.
How can I get content from file and write it to dataframe?

Comment: What returns `None`?

Comment: @martineau content of file is empty and it returns `None`, but it doesn't empty. I need to read that and add to dataframe

Comment: What is the value of `all_files`?

Comment: @errata It's list. I filter list in directory and next I add it's name to `sftp.get()`

Comment: @PetrPetrov I know it is a list, I was asking for a value of it? :)

Comment: @errata: `all_files` is created in the third line of the code.

Comment: @martineau I can see that :)

Comment: @errata: Didn't sound like it. Anyhow, seems like it would be more pertinent to ask what the value of `today_log` was when the `get()` call returned `None`.

Comment: @martineau My initial question was "what is the value of `all_files`", not what type of variable is it or in which line is it :) Since `today_log` seems to be `None`, I was wondering what is the value of `all_files` because `today_log` should be the first element of `all_files`... :)

Comment: @errata there are names of files, that I need to get  from directory. I try to get content of file with it's name. But it can't be None, because it's size is 45Mb

Comment: @PetrPetrov Do you see the desired output (content) of that file when you run `sftp.open(all_files[0])` (immediately after the first `all_files = ...` line)? Btw, if I am right, `sftp.listdir()` will return you files in "arbitrary" order, meaning that you might not get the same file in position `0` every time...

Comment: @errata `sftp.open()` returns `<paramiko.sftp_file.SFTPFile object at 0x105e82080>`. How can I show data from it?

Comment: @errata can you say, i check my directory with code, and now there are some files from server. What should I use only to read that, but not saving to my pc?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to read the file from SFTP server into a variable/memory.

For that, you need to use [`.getfo`](https://pysftp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pysftp.html#pysftp.Connection.getfo), like:

```
flo = BytesIO()
sftp.getfo(remotepath, flo)
```

---

Alternatively, use Paramiko library directly (without the pysftp wrapper).
See [Read a file from server with ssh using python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1596963/850848).