# Downloading file with pysftp

Tags: python, sftp, pysftp

I'm trying to load (and directly save locally) a `.csv` file stored on a FTP Server (SFTP protocol). I'm using Python in combination with pysftp library. When I check if the file exists, it returns TRUE. But when trying to load the file, it seems to be empty, whatever I try.

How can I get (and store) the file to my local environment? Do I miss something obvious?

```
import pysftp

cnopts = pysftp.CnOpts()
cnopts.hostkeys = None

# Make connection to sFTP
with pysftp.Connection(hostname,
                       username=sftp_username,
                       password=sftp_pw,
                       cnopts = cnopts
                       ) as sftp:
    sftp.isfile('directory/file.csv')) ## TRUE
    file = sftp.get('directory/file.csv')
    print(file) ## None

sftp.close()
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

[`Connection.get`](https://pysftp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pysftp.html#pysftp.Connection.get) does not return anything. It downloads the remote file to a local path specified by the `localpath` argument. If you do not specify the argument, it downloads the file to the current working directory.

So if you want to download to a specific local directory instead, you want this:

```
sftp.get('directory/file.csv', '/local/path/file.csv')
```

---

If you really want to read the file to a variable (what I understand that you actually do not want), you need to use [`Connection.getfo`](https://pysftp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pysftp.html#pysftp.Connection.getfo), like:

```
flo = BytesIO()
sftp.getfo(remotepath, flo)
flo.seek(0)
```

Alternatively, use Paramiko library directly (without the pysftp wrapper).
See [Read a file from server with SSH using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1596963/850848).

---

*Obligatory warning: Do not set `cnopts.hostkeys = None`, unless you do not care about security. For the correct solution see [Verify host key with pysftp](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38939454/850848)*.