# Download file from FTP using Python

Tags: python, csv, ftp

I'am trying to dowload a file YYYYMMDD_FCTall.csv from a FTP using Python but the code does not work. This is what I've done:

```
import pysftp
import time

cnopts = pysftp.CnOpts()
cnopts.hostkeys = None

# Make connection to sFTP
with pysftp.Connection("XX.XX.XX.X",
                       username="YYY_YY",
                       password="ZZZZ:",
                       cnopts = cnopts
                       ) as sftp:
    sftp.isfile('/route/route1/route3/FCTall/'+time.strftime("%Y%m%d")+'_FCTall.csv') ## TRUE
    #sftp.get(('/route/route1/route3/FCTall/'+time.strftime("%Y%m%d")+'_FCTall.csv', 'C:/Users/myuser/Documents/Python Scripts/'+time.strftime("%Y%m%d")+'_FCTall.csv')
    sftp.get(''+time.strftime("%Y%m%d")+'_FCTall.csv', 'C:/Users/myuser/Documents/Python Scripts/'+time.strftime("%Y%m%d")+'_FCTall.csv')
    #print(file) ## None

sftp.close()
```

Comment: Do you get an error message? If so, can you add it to your question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Downloading file with pysftp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44632588/downloading-file-with-pysftp)

Comment: "the code does not work" tells us nothing that we can assist you with :/

Answer (score 1):

Your call to `isfile` and `get` are referring different files.

The first is in absolute path. The latter is in relative path to your current FTP directory.

Solution is to align both pathnames. This should solve your problem.

Comment: I almost downvoted this ... but i think you are right ... please post it as an actual answer instead of what is by all rights simply a comment