# How can I check if a file contains a string on an SFTP server in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sftp, pysftp

I am able to connect to the server and see all the files in a given directory, however, I seem to always run into problems when I try to open a file.

The scenario is: I want to get the latest file based on date from an SFTP server, then I want to check if that file has a particular string in it. If it does, return true, if not return false. Here is my solution below:

```
def does_file_exists_on_sftp_server_and_contains_given_value(value):
    latest_date = 0
    latest_file = None
    retry_attempt = 0
    value_is_present= False

    while retry_attempt < 50:
        # the line below does the sftp server login and that works successfully 
        conn = vm_sftp_login()
        files = conn.listdir_attr("directory")
        for file in files:
            if file.filename.endswith(".xml") and file.st_mtime > latest_date:
                latest_date = file.st_mtime
                latest_file = file.filename
                retry_attempt = 50
        retry_attempt += 1
    latest_file_obj = conn.get(latest_file)
    file_obj = open(latest_file_obj)
    for line in file_obj:
        if value in line:
            value_is_present = True
            break
    return value_is_present
```

The code seems to break at this point: `latest_file_obj = conn.get(latest_file)`.

**Traceback**

```
self = <paramiko.sftp_client.SFTPClient object at 0x000001EF8E156748>
msg = paramiko.Message(b'\x00\x00\x00\x05\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x0cNo such file\x00\x00\x00\x00')

    def _convert_status(self, msg):
        """
            Raises EOFError or IOError on error status; otherwise does nothing.
            """
        code = msg.get_int()
        text = msg.get_text()
        if code == SFTP_OK:
            return
        elif code == SFTP_EOF:
            raise EOFError(text)
        elif code == SFTP_NO_SUCH_FILE:
            # clever idea from john a. meinel: map the error codes to errno
>           raise IOError(errno.ENOENT, text)
E           FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file
```

Comment: Please add the full traceback of the exception you're getting.

Comment: @glibdud added the traceback

Comment: Catch the exception and print the value of `latest_file`. That's what the server is looking for, and it's not finding it.

Comment: You sure latest_file is set? seems like there is a hole in your logic there to where latest_file cannot be set, and you blindly get what could be None

Comment: @sehafoc latest_file is set, the value when i check the variable is something like  latestfile = str'filename.xml'

Comment: @glibdud please check my comment above

Comment: You're providing the directory when you do the listdir, but it looks like it's not in the variable. Do you need to add it?

Comment: glib beat me to it haha, does the get need to be "directory/filename.xml"

Comment: you guys are right!... thanks a lot but still unable to open the file and read through it.

Comment: @glibdud you're right but then i now do something like this latest_file_obj = conn.get(f"vm-hints/{latest_file}") ... the result of lates_file_obj is None.. how come

Comment: See the [Paramiko SFTP documentation](http://docs.paramiko.org/en/2.4/api/sftp.html#paramiko.sftp_client.SFTPClient.get). `get()` expects you to pass a local filename to copy the file to. Although it doesn't explicitly say, it probably always returns `None`.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem might be that that particular line of code is trying to access the file `latest.xml` instead of `directory/latest.xml`. I'm not personally familiar with this library, but if `conn.listdir_attr()` works similarly to python's `os.listdir()`, then it omits the name of the folder from each of the filenames it returns. Thus, if you want to open a file from that list, you have to add the directory name back in.

So, try

```
latest_file_obj = conn.get('directory/' + latest_file)
```

instead and see if it works.

Comment: you're right but then i now do something like this latest_file_obj = conn.get(f"vm-hints/{latest_file}") ... the result of lates_file_obj is None.. how come

Comment: If you can, I recommend doing step-by-step debugging with a tool like pdb, or at least having the console print the value of every variable in the scope - it could be that the functions aren't behaving quite as you expect them to, and unfortunately I don't have enough experience with this library to make any more direct suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to specify a path to the file in `Connection.get`, as already answered by @a625993.
2. [`Connection.get`](https://pysftp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pysftp.html#pysftp.Connection.get) does not return anything. It downloads the remote file to a local path specified by the `localpath` argument. If you do not specify the argument, it downloads the file to the current working directory.

   If you really want to read the file to a variable (what I understand that you actually do not want), you need to use [`.getfo`](https://pysftp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pysftp.html#pysftp.Connection.getfo), like:

   ```
   flo = BytesIO()
   sftp.getfo(remotepath, flo)
   ```

   Alternatively, use Paramiko library directly (without the pysftp wrapper).
   See [Read a file from server with ssh using python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1596963/850848).